# Draw line between two given points (OpenCV, Python)

Tags: python, opencv, point, lines

I am struggling with this problem for an hour by now...

I have an image with a rectangle inside:

[image: rect]

This is the code I wrote to find the points for the corners:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


img = cv2.imread('rect.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = np.float32(gray)

points = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, 100, 0.01, 10)
points = np.int0(points)

for point in points:
    x, y = point.ravel()
    cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 3, (0, 255, 0), -1)

print(points[0])
print(points[1])
print(points[2])
print(points[3])

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imwrite('rect.png', img)
```

This is the result:

[image: rst]

As you can see, it works perfect. What I want is to draw a line along the upper/lower points (x1,x2 - x3,x4).

What I produced since now is this...

```
cv2.line(img, (points[0]), (points[1]), (0, 255, 0), thickness=3, lineType=8)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But it doesn't work.

Any idea ?

The result should be like this:

[image: out]

The two lines must pass along the coordinates of the points. `print(points[0])` above give the next output, as example:

```
[[561 168]]
[[155 168]]
[[561  53]]
[[155  53]]
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you try `cv2.line(img, points[0].ravel(), points[1].ravel(), (0, 255, 0), thickness=3, lineType=8)` please?

Comment: Did it, give error `new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple`

Comment: try `cv2.line(img,(561,168),(155,168),(0,255,0),3) `. If it works probably you are passing the points wrongly

Comment: Yes, this will work but the points must stay in a variable. I can't give them manually.. Also, the line have to be along this axis, not just to connect the two points..

Comment: @api55 printing `points[0]` that will give `[[561 168]]`

Comment: have you tried points[0][0]?

Comment: Yes, even `points[0][0][0]` but nothing

Comment: I used (points[0][0][0],points[0][0][1]) but the ravel function is generating some form of random walk around the edges and the points[0]-[3] are different each time I run the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So first of all, let'S look at your print, it says that points[0] is

```
[[561 168]]
```

but opencv point is like

```
(561, 168)
```

You can unpack it like you did with the circle and then do the tuple

```
x, y = points[0].ravel()
(x,y)
```

or you can use

```
tuple(points[0].ravel())
```

or

```
tuple(points[0][0])
```

## Edit

You wanted from one side of the screen to the other one, that is also easy. What you need to do is change the x value to be 0 in one point and column value in the other point. I think the easiest way is to do it like this:

```
y = points[0].ravel()[1]
cv2.line(img, (0, y), (img.shape[1], y), (0, 255, 0), thickness=3, lineType=8)
```

Two things to note here:

1. As you can see I did not care about the second point, since I assumed
   that it will be in the same horizontal line, if not, it will get a
   little bit more complicated, but not hard.
2. img.shape returns the
   tuple with the image details as (rows, cols, channels), since we
   need cols we took [1].

Comment: Explained very well. From this, can the Silencer answer be combined to make the lines long (and not just limited to these two given points) or your answer have a different method ?

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted from point to point, give me a second and I fix it

Comment: It's right, it's ok from point to point. Just asking...Maybe add the second (long line answer) after the first, no edit the first. Thank you.

Comment: @BlueTrack sorry, it is shape without parenthesis :/ it is not a function, I already edited the answer

Answer (score 6):

```
points = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, 100, 0.01, 10)
points = np.int0(points).reshape(-1,2)

for point in points:
    x, y = point.ravel()
    cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 3, (0, 255, 0), -1)


y1 = min(points[:,1])
y2 = max(points[:,1])

## small and big enough 
cv2.line(img, (0, y1), (1000, y1), (0, 255, 0), thickness=3, lineType=8)
cv2.line(img, (0, y2), (1000, y2), (0, 255, 0), thickness=3, lineType=8)
```

Comment: Ladies and gentleman, we have a winner. This do the job straight the way. Can you try to explain as api55 did ? Thanks.